# ui-sref Not Firing in Ionic Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Having a lot of trouble getting a button to fire on a view. I am able to activate all of the pages that are in the tabs that I use as a menu.This specific button is just in the middle of a view. I have tried using a href, $state.go, and everything else I can think of. I changed the view to be a modal, and calling it using a function through ng-click, and that did work. Without being a modal, I can't get it to go.

My guess is that my states are set up wrong.

here is how I have my states:

```
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive

.state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })


  // request tab
  .state('tab.request', {
    url: '/request',
    views: {
      'tab-request': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-request.html',
        controller: 'RequestCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.new', {
      url: '/new',
      views: {
        'tab-new': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-new.html',
          controller: 'RequestCtrl'
        }
      }
    })


  // Ionic User tab
  .state('tab.incoming', {
    url: '/incoming',
    views: {
      'tab-incoming': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-incoming.html',
        controller: 'IncomingCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

then I'm trying to trigger it using either of these

```
<button class="button button-block button-stable button-outline" ui-sref="tab.new">
        Go to Page B
    </button>
              <a class="round-button" ui-sref="tab.new"><i class="ion-alert-circled button_icon"></i><br/>NEW REQUEST</a>
```

and this is the view I'm trying to display.

```
<ion-view view-title="Create Requests" >

  <ion-content class=" has-header" >
  <div class="row row-center">
      <div class="col-50 col-offset-25">

  </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? What other information is critical to determining what's wrong?
 I've been working on this for about 3 hours now with no luck from the internet.

Thank you!

Comment: You div tag `<div class="col-50 col-offset-25"` isn't closed properly. Is that a typo here or in your actual code?

Comment: that was a typo here only. thx!

Comment: in which page do you have your `<a class="round-button" ui-sref="tab.new">` code?